# Post pre-processing function for search indexing

Tags: php, post, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Is there a way you can run a post through a filter before it gets saved in order to identify what search terms should be associated with it.

For example, can you define that you want to replace hyphens with spaces in the search terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include this in your theme (in functions.php):

```
<?php

/**
 * Creates a list of keywords associated with the post
 * and stores the value in a custom field called "search keywords"
 */
add_filter('save_post', function () {
    global $post;

    // Get post content
    $words = strtolower($post->post_title . ' ' . $post->post_content);

    /* Do any extra processing here */    

    // Save
    if (!add_post_meta($post->ID, 'search keywords', $words, true)) { 
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'search keywords', $words);
    }
});

/**
 * This is needed to search against a custom field
 */
add_filter('posts_join', function ($join) {
    global $wpdb;

    if (!is_search()) {
        return $join;
    }

    $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON (
        $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'search keywords'
    ) ";

    return $join;
});

/**
 * This filters the actual search result
 */
add_filter('posts_where', function ($where) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Only change the search function
    if (!is_search()) {
        return $where;
    }

    // Get the search terms
    $search_query = strtolower(get_search_query());
    $search_terms = explode(' ', $search_query);

    // Only show published posts
    $where = " AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' ";

    // Only show posts, not any other post types
    $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_type IN ('post') ";

    // Search
    $where .= " AND ( 0 ";

    foreach ($search_terms as $search_term) {
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
            " OR (0
                OR ($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%%%s%%')
                OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%%%s%%')
                OR (1
                    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'search keywords'
                    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%'
                )
            ) ",
            $search_term,
            $search_term,
            $search_term
        );
    }

    $where .= " ) ";

    return $where;
});
```